# Prove that $f(M)$ is a smooth surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $f:R^3→R^3$ diffeomorphism. Prove that for every smooth surface $M \subset R^3$ the set $f(M)$ is also a smooth surface. So to prove that $f(M)$is a smooth surface I need to find a smooth parametrization (1-1 differentiable onto with continuous inverse) $ψ:W⊂R^2→f(M)$ for $f(M)$ to be surface. So I have something like this ($φ$ is a smooth parametrization since I know M is a smooth surface).

$$\begin{array} MM&\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}&f(M)\\
\uparrow{φ}&&\uparrow{ψ=?}\\
U\subset R{^2}&\stackrel{??}{\longrightarrow}&W\subset R{^2}\
\end{array}$$

I need to find $ψ$. Will $ψ=φ \circ f$ work?

Comment: Yes! It will work.

Comment: And my thinking is right? I mean it does indeed suffices to find a function(parametrization) with those properties to prove that the set is indeed a surface.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: No, it's $\psi = f\circ\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

[The restriction of a diffeomorphism to an open submanifold is a diffeomorphism onto its image](http://file:///C:/Users/moell/Downloads/9781441999818-c2.pdf). So your composition should work. That is, if $\lbrace \varphi_\lambda\rbrace_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a collection of charts for $M$ then $\lbrace f\circ \varphi_\lambda\rbrace_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a collection of charts for $f(M)$.